# Check the existence of file

Tags: shell, unix

I need to check the existence of file in Unix.If file exists then I have to delete the file from that location.

```
if ( file exists)
 then 
   delete the file
fi
```

Comment: why not just delete if i.e. `/bin/rm -f <filename>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[ -e file ] && rm file
```

Comment: This may lead to errors of the form: `rm: cannot remove 'file': Is a directory`

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
if [ -f /home/mfyounus/test/aaa ];  then

    rm -f /home/mfyounus/test/aaa
    echo "File \"/home/mfyounus/test/aaa\" Deleted"

else 

    echo "File not found"

fi
```

Comment: This only works if the file is a "regular" file - it will fail if it's a block device, symlink, FIFO or directory, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably best to do `rm -f test`
This will ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt.

If you want to know the file exists and then remove you can do

```
test -f file && { echo "File exists. Deleting it"; rm -f file ; }
```